# How to fix exim error : SMTP timeout after initial connection: Operation timed out

Tags: docker, smtp, gmail, exim, exim4

Hi am trying to send notification using exim docker image and am getting below error
am trying to send mail from mailid@domain.com  to username.gmail.com

```
2023-07-27 05:36:21 1qOtfh-00000C-0E <= mailid@domain.com H=(b0264265d64d) [192.168.0.3] P=esmtp S=718 id=348112319.0.1690436181096.JavaMail.mailid@domain.com
2023-07-27 05:38:31 1qOtfh-00000C-0E H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.200.27]: SMTP timeout after initial connection: Operation timed out
2023-07-27 05:42:53 1qOtfh-00000C-0E H=alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [142.250.141.27]: SMTP timeout after initial connection: Operation timed out
```

am using alpine based docker image

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN echo -en 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main\n\
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing\n\
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community\n' >> /etc/apk/repositories

RUN apk update && apk --update add exim tini && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/exim && \
touch /var/log/exim/mainlog /var/log/exim/paniclog /var/log/exim/rejectlog && \
chown exim:exim /var/log/exim/*log

COPY exim.conf /etc/exim/

COPY main.cf /etc/postfix/

COPY resolv.conf /etc/


ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini"]

CMD ["/usr/sbin/exim", "-bd", "-q10m"]

EXPOSE 25
```

and  my exim config look like below

```
dnslookup:
      driver = dnslookup
      domains = ! +local_domains
      transport = remote_smtp
      ignore_target_hosts = 0.0.0.0 : 127.0.0.0/8
      # if ipv6-enabled then instead use:
      # ignore_target_hosts = <; 0.0.0.0 ; 127.0.0.0/8 ; ::1
      self = pass
      no_more
```

please help me .Thanks in advance

Comment: 2023-07-27 07:44:06 1qOux9-00000C-2m ==mailid@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-54): retry time not reached for any host for 'gmail.com'